# How to execute Map Reduce job with input parameters from a config file

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to execute a MR job where in I want to pass the parameters to the job through a config file. Also the same parameters should be used in the mapper and the reducer. Which API is best suited to achieve this?

Comment: This question was asked to understand the way we can achieve using an external file while running a MR job. This requires using different API which many may not be aware of. This question is very helpful to those. Please consider still holding this question.

Comment: To be honest: this is a very relevant question, a while ago I had the same question but google nor SO showed a simple answer, it's therefore not a bad idea to have this precise question here. I have explained the DBCache solution on a number of SO questions but they were usually asking a different question.

Comment: Hi laalto, LaurentG, greg-449, devolus, Suresh. Please see the comment from irW and reconsider holding the question. You are blocking better answer to the same problem which others might be facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config file can be added to the DistributedCache, I will show you how it's done in my code:

To read the file in your mapper or reducer, the easiest thing is to open it from distributed cache in the setup of your mapper/reducer:

```
@Override
protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException,
                    InterruptedException {

            Path[] uris = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(context
                    .getConfiguration());

            String patternsFile = uris[0].toString();


            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(patternsFile));
           ...

            in.close();



        }
```

To add it to the cache add the following while setting up the job:

```
try {
            DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI(filename), job.getConfiguration());

        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            System.out.println("URI exception: "+filename);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Could you please show me the way to invoke the same file and read the arguments placed in the file while running the job?

Comment: Once you got the BufferedReader just use: in.readLine() this reads a line of the config file.